# Google-Chrome-stable immediately closes on startup

Tags: 11.04, google-chrome

Hi I installed and reinstalled google-chrome-stable chrome and chromium from the synaptic package manager. Each time I try to use the browser it closes.

When I tried to open the browser from terminal, this is what the machine did:

> $ google-chrome
>   [2731:2747:760246373:ERROR:cookie_monster.cc(958)] Found 1 duplicate cookies for >host='google.com', with {name='PREF', domain='.google.com', path='/'}
>   [2731:2731:762969060:FATAL:syncable.cc(1557)] Check failed: successor.good(). 
>   Aborted.

Any thoughts on how to address the duplicate cookie issue and getting chrome up and running?

Thanks

Comment: chromium bug with the same error: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=43190

Comment: This should be followed up in the bug report, not here.

Answer (score 2):

Annoying isn't it?

Read through the following 5 steps and decide for yourself whether you give it a go.

1. Uninstall Chromium using the ubuntu software centre. My guess is that chromium and chrome might interfere with each other.
2. When done, open the update-manager (system>>Administration>>Update Manager, then click Settings, key in your password when prompted, then click the tab named "Other software")
3. Check that Google Chrome is in your apt repository is registered as **http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/    stable main** (notice the space between "deb/" and "stable main")
4. if it is **NOT** correct, click **remove**, and either (4.A) go to http://www.google.com/chrome?platform=linux using the browser that works, or alternatively (4.B) click on **add**, and type exactly: 
   deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
5. then press "close" and let the repository update itself. Once done open a terminal and type: sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable and press enter.
6. When done at either 4.A or 5 try google-chrome again from your menu :-) Should work now....

Note: When using your webbrowser as noted in 5.a. Google Chrome will add the Google repository, so your system will keep Google Chrome up to date automatically. If you don't want Google's repository, do "sudo touch /etc/default/google-chrome" before installing the package.

Comment: Thanks for the support. I realised my problem was not deleting google-chrome folder in .config. Once I did that it was a simple install process!